# Subsetting Dataframe by Column Name

Tags: python, subset

I have a dataframe with columns that contain "pre_1, pre_2, pre_3, etc...". I also have post data labelled as "post1, post2, post3...etc).

Is there a way to slice data in Python by selecting ALL columns with the word 'pre'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` with `like` or `regex` keyword to match patterns in the column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'pre_1': [1,2],
    'pre_2': [3,4],
    'pre_3': [5,6],
    'post1': [7,8],
    'post2': [9,10],
    'post3': [11,12]
})

df
#post1  post2   post3   pre_1   pre_2   pre_3
#0   7      9      11       1       3       5
#1   8     10      12       2       4       6
```

---

To select columns that contain a pattern, use the `like` keyword:

```
df.filter(like='pre')

#pre_1  pre_2   pre_3
#0   1      3       5
#1   2      4       6
```

---

Or you can use regular expression, the following will select columns that starts(`^`) with `pre`:

```
df.filter(regex='^pre')

#pre_1  pre_2   pre_3
#0   1      3       5
#1   2      4       6
```